# How to simulate complete user input with events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, mouseevent

I need to simulate a user input in an input field:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
```

The following events should get triggered manually:

> mousedown > focus > mouseup > click > keydown > keypress > change >
>   blur

**Code show here**

If I use this code, they should get detected:

```
var element = document.getElementById('name');

$(element).on('mousedown focus mouseup click keydown keypress change blur', function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

Updated file (doesn't get detected, no console logs..):

```
$("#name").trigger("mousedown");
$("#name").trigger("focus");
$("#name").trigger("mouseup");
$("#name").trigger("click");
$("#name").trigger("keydown");
$("#name").trigger("keypress");
$("#name").trigger("change");
$("#name").trigger("blur");

var element = document.getElementById('name');

$(element).on('mousedown focus mouseup click keydown keypress change blur', function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Check out `trigger` for jquery : http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @AmitDas it doesn't get detected.. :(

Comment: @MaxGrünfeld show us what you tried.

Comment: @Taplar see "Updated file" above

Comment: You're trying to trigger before you've created the binding...

Comment: @Taplar You're still the best :). Thanks bro.

Comment: @Taplar I noticed that several settings are missing. For example clientX: 79 and clientY: 23. Can I add them?

Comment: A simulated event is not going to have all the properties of a real event.  I'm not sure what all you can set, but the browser will always know it's simulated, and you cannot make it appear as a non-simulated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use jQuery's `trigger` for this. So, if you wanted to simulate the events in the order you described:

```
$("#name").trigger("mousedown");
$("#name").trigger("focus");
$("#name").trigger("mouseup");
$("#name").trigger("click");
$("#name").trigger("keydown");
$("#name").trigger("keypress");
$("#name").trigger("change");
$("#name").trigger("blur");
```

If you want to really similuate a user, you could use some `setTimeout` to simulate human delay as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it doesn't get detected with `$(element).on('...', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try This --

Add Jquery plugin

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="name">

//var element = document.getElementById('name');

$("input").trigger("mousedown");
$("input").trigger("focus");
$("input").trigger("mouseup");
$("input").trigger("click");
$("input").trigger("keydown");
$("input").trigger("keypress");
$("input").trigger("change");
$("input").trigger("blur");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the trigger [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function to simulate and trigger any events.

Comment: This s a link only answer, which are considered to be very low quality.